# Using text styles that are not included in DLS

Tags: typography, interface-design, design-principles

We have 15 text styles in our Design Language System and sometimes I face some situations that I have to use some other text styles instead of the existing ones. Is it weird to use some typography styles that they were not in our DLS as a defined text style?

Answer (score 2):

Most style guides simply *can't* account for all use cases.

The decision of how and when to diverge from a style guide ultimately comes down to who is in charge and often how severe the divergence. If you are in charge, then it's your call.

I find as long as I'm sticking with defined fonts and colors, then things should be okay. It's not uncommon to break for sizing or spacing due to a specific instance. However, introducing new fonts, colors, faces, etc. may not be appropriate

Comment: Thank you @Scott

Comment: @MasoodFarsaei If you feel that an answer posted has answered your question you can click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as "correct".